# Remmina: why not display full screen?

Tags: 19.04, remote-desktop, remmina

I installed Remmina to access remote virtual PC on Windows.

```
Remmina - 1.3.3 (git n/a)

RDP RDP Plugin: 1.3.3 (git n/a), Compiled with FreeRDP lib: 2.0.0-dev5 (2693389a+debian), Running with FreeRDP lib: 2.0.0-dev5 (rev 2693389a+debian), H264: No
RDPF RDP Plugin: 1.3.3 (git n/a), Compiled with FreeRDP lib: 2.0.0-dev5 (2693389a+debian), Running with FreeRDP lib: 2.0.0-dev5 (rev 2693389a+debian), H264: No
RDPS RDP Plugin: 1.3.3 (git n/a), Compiled with FreeRDP lib: 2.0.0-dev5 (2693389a+debian), Running with FreeRDP lib: 2.0.0-dev5 (rev 2693389a+debian), H264: No
SFTP 1.3.3     
SSH  1.3.3     
VNC 1.3.3     
VNCI 1.3.3     
glibsecret 1.3.3     

Build configuration: HAVE_ARPA_INET_H=1 HAVE_ERRNO_H=1 HAVE_FCNTL_H=1 HAVE_NETDB_H=1 HAVE_NETINET_IN_H=1 HAVE_NETINET_TCP_H=1 HAVE_SYS_SOCKET_H=1 HAVE_SYS_UN_H=1 HAVE_TERMIOS_H=1 HAVE_UNISTD_H=1 WITH_APPINDICATOR=ON WITH_AVAHI=ON WITH_FREERDP=ON WITH_GCRYPT=ON WITH_GETTEXT=ON WITH_IPP=OFF WITH_LIBRARY_VERSIONING=ON WITH_LIBSECRET=ON WITH_LIBSSH=ON WITH_LIBVNCSERVER=ON WITH_MANPAGES=ON WITH_SPICE=ON WITH_SSE2=ON WITH_TELEPATHY=ON WITH_TRANSLATIONS=ON WITH_VTE=ON
Build type:          None
CFLAGS:              -g -O2 -fdebug-prefix-map=/build/remmina-sBKSjU/remmina-1.3.3+dfsg=. -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fPIC -Wall -g
Compiler:            GNU, 

8.3.0
Target architecture: x64
```

When I connecting to remote PC, it shows only a part of screen:

[image]

Please, tell me, how to fix it & to show full screen.

OS: Ubuntu 19.04.

Answer (score 4):

Unfortunately I haven't found any decent rdp for linux yet to reach the level of native windows or Microsoft's rdp for mac.
Remmina does not show the remote desktop full size (or I couldn't make it to work).

To my surprise a cli tool called **rdesktop** works good enough.

`rdesktop <host-ip>`

Of course you can specify username and password and other options before making the connection and create an alias so you don't have to type each time.

For example:

```
alias rdp='rdesktop -u Administrator -p mypass 10.10.1.10'
```

If you want to have a shared folder to transfer files between the 2 machines:

```
alias rdp='rdesktop -u Administrator -p mypass 10.10.1.10 -r disk:myshare=/home/user'
```

[image]

Comment: works brilliantly on Ubuntu

Answer (score 2):

What i did was, create the connection at the "New connection Profile" button. Then you have to set your connection settings (server,domain, user, password....) and you can set your display settings.

Comment: Yes, first I connected via the ip address field box, it was 500x400 (somewhat) resolution, then I created a New connection & saved it, now everything works on my screen resolution

Answer (score 1):

In the sidebar of the Remmina screen, there is an option to show the full screen:

[image]

Comment: It goes full screen but inside that does not show up full size.

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same issue till found the solution somewhere. create a connection profile, and while doing this choose the option "use client resolution" in topic "resolution", save the profile (of course after entering credintials) and that's it.
whenever you need to connect just use the saved profile.

Comment: Yes it worked for me connecting from Fedora 34 to Windows 10. Thanks you very much.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem might be [related to this](https://superuser.com/questions/1405707/in-ubuntu-16-04-connecting-through-vino-only-shows-the-top-leftmost-screen-hig), which occurs when connecting to high DPI displays. It is a [reported bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/vino/+bug/1668309) in vino which so far AFAIK is not solved.

Answer (score 0):

`rdesktop` Worked for me on Ubuntu 20.04

It does not come preinstalled. Here's the command to install it
`sudo apt install rdesktop`

To open the rdesktop with mentioned username in fullscreen mode, use below command
`rdesktop -u username -f IP`

Answer (score 0):

I also run into the same issue, he key for me seemed to be a button once you enter into full screen mode (it was full screen but the remote computer was still small), after that i pressed a button from the remina gui with an arrow up and down (in the middle of the menu) and that fixed it for me.
[this is the menu screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HPZef.png)

Answer (score 0):

Clicking 'Toggle dynamic resolution update' button fixed the issue for me

Answer (score 0):

From the Remmina sidebar:

- Set "Toggle scaled mode" off
- Set "Toggle dynamic resolution update" on
- Set "Toggle full screen mode" on

You should now have a full screen session on one monitor using the native resolution of your local display.

If you have multiple monitors Remmina will support this by setting "Multi monitor" on.  In conjunction with the steps above this will give you a full-screen session across all your monitors.

Remmina sidebar buttons use icons only but hovering your mouse over the icon will display the help text used in the list above.